# crm 2016 add custom filter for inline Lookup Control For Subgrid

Tags: crm, subgrid, dynamics-crm-2016

I'm using CRM2016 and in Opportunity form, I have a subgrid of OpportunityProduct which can be added more by click on + button and then choose existing products by opening an inline lookup.

I have a business to filter out some products that match my condition in JavaScript.

Can I add custom filter for this inline lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is a special grid.  It's not customizable via the client side API.  Your options are as follows:

1. Dig through the client side code to see if you can find a hook into that lookup.  I wouldn't recommend this.  It's unsupported and liable to break with any update.
2. Write a RetrieveMultiple plugin against OpportunityProduct that does some filtering for you.  The problem is that the filtering will have to be pretty static because you won't have any way to pass form parameters to the plugin.